# Why does colspan affect html table borders

Tags: html, css

So I stumbled onto something that seems strange to me.

For example, the following code:

```
<html>
    <table style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="8" style="border:3px solid black;">Title</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border:2px solid black; width:175px">Destination</td>
            <td style="border:2px solid black;" colspan="2">STR</td>
            <td></td>
            <td style="border:2px solid black;" colspan="2">Order Date</td>
            <td style="border:2px solid black;" colspan="2">24/jan/14</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border:2px solid black;">SV Truck nr</td>
            <td style="border:2px solid black;" colspan="2">SV92566T/24JAN</td>
            <td></td>
            <td style="border:2px solid black;" colspan="2">Order time</td>
            <td style="border:2px solid black;" colspan="2">18HO</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height:20px">
            <td colspan="8" style="border:0"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</html>
```

Now, I would think that this would result in a nice table structure with an empty column **without borders** in the middle. As long as you wouldn't include that

```
<tr style="height:20px">
    <td colspan="8" style="border:0"></td>
</tr>
```

it does, in fact.
So my question is why does this happen?

I'm telling the new row (which I would think has nothing to do with the previous one) that I don't want any border. But as long as I span that empty, borderless row across my 8 columns a border is added across the bottom of the previously borderless column of the previous row.

I know that I can fix this by not spanning my empty row and just leaving it as an empty `<tr style="height:20px"></tr>` but I would really like to just understand why this happens.

Also, I know that inline style is normally definitely not the way to go, but this is for an html company email, so I'm afraid I have no other option.

Comment: do you actually have 8 columns anywhere in this table? if not what is the point in the `colspan="2"` cells? [Is that what you like what you are after](http://jsfiddle.net/XXnX7/)

Comment: This does not seem to occur anywhere but Chrome. In other browsers there is never a bottom border regardless of whether you have the last `td[colspan="8"]`.

Comment: @Pete Well yeah, further down from this code, but that part and the actual amount of columns wasn't important for the question, so I left those out.

Comment: @BoltClock Really? Damn it, testing the finished thing across browsers/email clients is going to be such a pain.

Comment: Ah, I never tested in chrome! so I wasn't quite sure what the problem was, I see now!

Comment: I think it's got to do with the border-collapse - if you remove this it works although then you get double borders - http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/XXnX7/3/.  If you have a white background you can just set the border color of the [empty cell](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/XXnX7/5/)

Comment: @Pete Yeah, seems like Chrome has some specific logic behind the border-collapse that might cause this. At the moment I don't have a problem with leaving my empty row entirely empty though, so I'll stick to that as a "solution'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solves the problem in Chrome:

```
<tr style="height:20px">
  <td colspan="8" style="border:3px solid transparent"></td>
</tr>
```

Don't know why the border has to be at least `3px`, but it works.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/svk6tqs9/)